# MSE vs SNR in MATLAB, Matrix 7*1

Tags: matlab

```
n=50;
x=2;
snr = -5:5:25;
zi = zeros(7,50);
mu = 1;
for i=1:length(snr)
    sigma(1,i) =  sqrt(1/(10^(snr(1,i)/10)));
    %Let wi be gaussian ditribution with mean mu= 1 and sigma found above
    wi = normrnd(mu,sigma(1,i),[1,n]);
    zi(i,:) = x + wi;
end
```

I found zi using the above code but the matrix comes is 7 * 50.  what I assume from the question is the answer should be 7 * 1 matrix. Can anyone help me please? Thank you

Answer (score -1):

```
function check3
clc
n=1;
    x=2;
    snr = -5:5:25;
    zi = zeros(7,1);
    mu = 1;
    for i=1:length(snr)
        sigma(1,i) =  sqrt(1/(10^(snr(1,i)/10)));             
        wi = normrnd(mu,sigma(1,i),[1,n]);
        zi(i,:) = x + wi;
    end
    zi
```

**Explanation**

I have simply replaced 50 by 1 in the original code. Thank you.

Comment: How did you change the OP's code? How does this help achieve their goal? Answers with explanation are considered much better than code-only answers.

Comment: @beaker, as the OP was looking for result which is 7 × 1 , I have simply replaced 50 in the code by 1.

Comment: I will put explation as you say in the code @beaker